# ORACLE subtraction from user defined variable

Tags: sql, oracle

what I'm trying to accomplish is to subtract 1 month from user given date variable. My code in where conditions is as following:

```
CONDITION >= to_char(add_months('&datum_od', 1), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

I am getting "ORA-1843: not a valid month" error.

Could you guys please help me out here?

Comment: The CONDITION  does not make sense

Comment: What value do you provide for &datum_od?

Comment: What is the type of `CONDITION`? If it's a date, you have to remove the `to_char` and if it's a varchar, you are comparing dates treating them as strings, and this will likely give a wrong result. Also, `add_months` accepts a date, while you are passing it a string: you should add a `to_date` to trasmform the input in a date, by using the appropriate format. Also if you want to subtract, you probably need -1 in `add_months`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - value for datum_od is date in format dd.mm.yyyy and the condition is one of the columns

Comment: The condition make no sense because in strings comparison '09.01.2001' > '01.01.2016'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_date(CONDITION,'dd.mm.yyyy') >= add_months(to_date('&datum_od','dd.mm.yyyy'), -1)
```

---

Please notice

- If the dates are stored as strings (why?) the format should contain **YYYY**, **MM** and **DD** in that order ,e.g. '**YYYY-MM-DD**', '**YYYYMMDD**' etc.
- for subtraction you have to use **-1**

Comment: Thank you Dudu, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Error suggest that you ave incorrect format of date. Probably caused by `&datum_od` is in other format than NLS date.

Try:

```
CONDITION >= to_char(add_months(to_date(&datum_od,'yyyy-mm-dd'), 1), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

And pass your variable `&datum_od` in format specified.

Next thing is why do you do `>=` comparison on strings not on dates? `To_char` seems wrong here.